# Can't use external dependencies in Angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I've created an Angular2 project with [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) but when I try to install external dependencies the compiler doesn't move the folder from node_modules to dist/vendor.

This is what I've done:

```
$ npm install --save angular2-google-maps
$ ng serve
```

My component file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/contact/contact.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/contact/contact.css'],
  providers: [],
  directives: [ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES],
  pipes: []
})
export class Contact {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
  constructor() {}
}
```

when I run **ng serve** and go to the web browser I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4200/angular2-google-maps/core

Answer (score 0):

As written in the guidelines : https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#package-installation

- have you include the script as followed ?

`<!-- ## ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE  ## -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js"></script>`

- have you injected the script as followed ?

`bootstrap(AppComponent, [ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS]);`

Comment: The problem is that I can`t add the <script> reference because the compiler moves folders from node_modules to dist/vendor (dist is the public directory). And yes, I've added ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler moves any folder from `src` to `dist`. I’ve created a new folder in `src` called `vendor` with the external library so when the compiler moves this folder to `dist`, `src/vendor` merges with `dist/vendor` and the external library is now accesible.

I’ve also added the `<script>` reference. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding the following line to the packages configuration in system-config.ts:

```
/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    'angular2-google-maps': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```