# angular2-google-maps with angular2 app

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, angular2-google-maps

I have setup the [`angular2-google-map`](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html) with angular2 application.

And here is the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AgmCoreModule} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'AIzaSyAe3ci9yavJcWt7MaJE8DusAuZo-QeRqkU'}) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And i installed the angular2-google-maps with the command,

```
npm install angular2-google-maps --save
```

which got successfully installed. when i run the application with npm start,
it shows an error saying,

> http://localhost:3000/angular2-google-maps/core Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

but i can see the **angular2-google-maps** folder inside the node_modules.
what is the issue?

Comment: using webpack/System.js as module loader?

Comment: at the time of npm install, did it throw any warnings or exceptions, the least you can try now is npm install and then cache clean and then reinstall

Comment: @RahulSingh no it dint show any error

Comment: @PankajParkar no am using quickstart project which has system.js

Comment: did you tried this ways? 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970965/cant-use-external-dependencies-in-angular2

Comment: @Sajeetharan so take a look at below answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgotten to add `map` for in `system.config.js`

```
'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js'
```

By adding above to systemjs configuration. Module loader will understand to load `core.umd.js` when you tries to import `angular2-google-maps/core` .

Comment: now that error is gone, it shows Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check css file has been present on that path

Comment: i have fixed that too, now maps shows empty gray area, any idea?

Comment: Not sure, plunkr please